# How do I obtain the requires access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Until a few days ago the Python script I was using to generate an RSS feed for my own Facebook News Feed was working fine.  The script I was using first signed on to Facebook using my log in information and then called up this page and parsed it for an access token:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

I'm not sure that is exactly the way Facebook wants people to get an access token, but reading through all the information on Graph API I can't seem to find anything that says, "Here's how you get that token you need to access your own stuff."  It all seems to be directed at people trying to do far fancier stuff.

How do I obtain an access token such that the page referenced here will return the JSON format data I need?

res = browser.open('https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=%s' % acct)

Comment: You should be looking at the [Login documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/) that describe in depth what you need to do. Also I would suggest you take a look at the *unofficial* [SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk)

Comment: Far too much detail, most of which does not appear to be aimed at what I want to do, which should be very simple.  What I want is probably in here somewhere https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py you provide some Facebook page with Facebook issued credentials and it gives you back an access token to use with the graph api.  I suppose I have to sign up on Facebook to get the ID and SECRET codes. It was pretty simple in Twitter, I don't know why I can't find something equally as simple for Facebook.

Comment: This page seems to be what I want https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/ It seems to say I go somewhere and create an APP ID and an APP SECRET, then I go to a URL with those two items tacked onto it and get back an access token.  Hopefully getting those two items from Facebook will not be too difficult.

Comment: I don't know if this is progress or not. I got an APP ID and associated SECRET and plugged them into this string https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials which does yield an access token, but apparently not one that I can then use in the graph api call above to get my own news feed information. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by reading about [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/) as there are different types.
2. Then, to read the user news feed ([home connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home)), you need a *user `access_token`*
3. To retrieve one using the server-side method, you need to follow this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)
4. To understand the flow of the server-side method you can refer to this diagram (source: [Login Architecture document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/) ):
   [image]

Comment: Yes, I realize I need a user access token and I've seen this image.  Can the login dialog business be done without a UI though.  My previously working Python script did not need such a thing.

Comment: Just my five cents: Facebook API have many limitations. However, you can use reverse-engineering to understand how Facebook itself works with your master token. Master token can only be gained after an username / password authentication, and with this token you impersonate the user in its entirety. However, nobody will trust you if you require users to login with their passwords into your app, so this one is usually only useful for in-house solutions. It depends of what is your use case, however. Facebook will never like unofficial apps that work with master tokens, even if there are some.